# Multiple tkinter files quit one keep window open

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have been using Tkinter and I have it set up with a base background. I then open a file that adds my buttons and everything else. I will then have more files for the login and the game so on so on.

My main issue is closing the file. I could just use `place.forget` but what I really want to do is close the active file. I tried using `exit()` but all that does is close the window. so in short i want to close the file with the buttons but not the background file.

`file_name = background.py`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

top=Tk()

top.geometry("700x500")
top.resizable(False,False)
c=Canvas(top,bg="gray16",height=200,width=200)
c.pack()

filename=PhotoImage(file="mountain.png")

background_label=Label(top,image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)

canvas=Canvas(width=400,height=330)
canvas.place(x=150,y=70)

exec(open("./Home_screen.py").read())

top.mainloop()
```

this basically creates a graphical background and main window

`file_name = Home_screen.py`

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


def rem():
        loginPage.place_forget()


loginPage=Button(text="Login", width=20, command=lambda:[rem()], border=2)
loginPage.place(x=271,y=270)
```

what I would like to do is remove the .place_forget and replace it by closing Home_screen.py

Comment: Tkinter widgets (like all Python objects) have absolutely no ongoing connection to the file containing the code that created them.  In your specific case, the file was actually closed *before* the contents were executed.

Comment: What `Home_screen.py` does is just creating a `Login` button, so what do you mean by *"closing Home_screen.py"*?

Comment: @acw1668 it is just an example I have an entire login page and what I would like to do is just stop the login page from running. in my example above it is just the login button. stopping it from running leaves the page blank ready for the next file to open up which will be settings or the game

Comment: Without knowing how you create the *login page*, how can we know how to destroy it?

Comment: @acw1668 I  just want the file to close not destroy or hide